# Mechanize Selecting a Form and entering Text

Tags: python, mechanize

I am trying to automatically input text on a webpage and parse the resulting page in Python. After some research here I found this piece of code which should help me with that:

```
from mechanize import Browser
br = Browser()
br.set_handle_robots( False )
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]
br.open( "http://warframe.market" )
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form[ 'search-item' ] = 'Primed Chamber'
br.submit()
resp = resp.get_data()
print content
```

However, I can't seem to find the right form name/number and the form control. I tried analyzing the webpage's code, but the text field in which I try to enter my text isn't even a form. I was also unable to locate the script/url which is called by clicking the "Get!" button next to the text area.

The website in question is: https://warframe.market and I'd like to enter text in the big central search field (says "Name:"), click "Get!" and take a look at the resulting page; all of this silently in Python.

Answer (score 0):

**Selenium with PhantomJS webdriver** can help you do that, enter the text in the selected text box using **findelement with help of xpath** and click the Get button.
It seems like the text that we enter, the websites gives out suggestions and only for those words that are relevant/exist in the inventory, website would give the results.